# I am unable to find clone() method's implementation in Java's Object class.

Tags: java, object

While checking the source code of Java's object class, i am confused that if its the topmost non-abstract class in hierarchy, how can we leave the clone() method unimplemented? I understand that Cloneable interface acts as a marker interface to indicate that its legal to clone that particular object which implements Cloneable, just not able to find the implementation of the clone() method. Is it a part of the JVM?

Comment: Cloneable isn't used or talked about much these days.

Comment: If you must make a Cloneable, read Joshua Bloch's "Effective Java".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's defined as `protected native Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException;`

Being a native method, its implementation is not visible in the java sources.

Comment: the answer here tells where to find the source code, it is actually part of JVM: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12032292/is-it-possible-to-find-the-source-for-a-java-native-method